# Prove that a set $O \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is open with respect to the euclidean metric if and only if $O$ is open with respect to the maximum metric

Tags: metric-spaces

I have recently started learning about metric spaces and since I'm having a hard time understanding some of the basics, I tried doing some exercises and I got stuck on this one:

Prove that a set $O \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is open with respect to the euclidean metric if and only if $O$ is open with respect to the maximum metric.

As I understand it, a set $A \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is defined to be open with respect to the euclidean metric, if $\forall x \in A: \exists \epsilon > 0: B_\epsilon(x) \subset A$, where $B_\epsilon(x) = \{y \in \mathbb{R}^2 | d_2(x, y) < \epsilon\}$ and $d_2(x, y) = (|x_1 - y_1|^2 + |x_2 - y_2|^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$. Analogous with the maximum metric $d_\infty(x, y) = max\{ |x_1 - y_1|, |x_2 - y_2| \}$

My problem now is that I haven't yet had much experience in proving sets to be open and I don't know how to solve or tackle this issue with the maximum metric.

Comment: **HINT** It suffices to show that inside any euclidean ball, you always have a maximum ball. Inn fact, it suffices to show that inside any euclidean ball centered at the origin, there is always a maximum ball contained in it.

Comment: But wouldn't that only show that any open set with respect to the euclidean metric is also open with respect to the maximum metric? What about the other way around?

Comment: The other way is also true.
Recall that a maximum ball is a square with sides parallel to axis. So, inside a circle (an euclidean ball) you always can INSCRIBE such a square and inside such a squere you always can inscribe a circle. MOREOVER, the center of all squares and circles is THE SAME.

Comment: Ok, so if I want to prove the equivalence in the "$\Rightarrow$" direction, so $O$ is open with respect to the euclidean metric, I just take a point $x \in O$ and since such an $\epsilon$ exists, I can always find a maximum ball or square inside a circle with radius $\epsilon$. Specifically a square with side length $\sqrt(2)*\epsilon$ centered at the center of the circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : use that
$$\forall x,y\in \mathbb R^2, \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}d_\infty(x,y) \leq d_2(x,y)\leq d_\infty(x,y)$$

Comment: Thank you. I think this is similar, if not the same conclusion, I arrived at with the help of @Tito Eliatron, where we use the fact, that one can always fit a square inside a circle and the other way around.

Comment: This is just a different way to say the same thing